# can't ping the GW when configure linux with two vlans?

Tags: linux, cisco, vlan

my scenario:

```
vlan1 <--------> [interface0/1] L3 Switch [interface0/2]<-----------> vlan2
```

by follow this [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html):

vlan1 have one linux machine:

I Configure Linux to have 2 Virtual Local Area Network `eth0.1`,`eth0.2`:

[root@dd ~]# ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:48:23:C0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe48:23c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:267464 (261.1 KiB)  TX bytes:41002 (40.0 KiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

eth0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:48:23:C0  
          inet addr:192.168.2.3  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe48:23c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:6228 (6.0 KiB)
eth0.1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:48:23:C0  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe48:23c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:6228 (6.0 KiB)
```

I configure L3 Switch interface0/1 to be part of vlan1 and configure vlan1 interface to have the address:

```
ip address 192.168.1.1
```

the problem is I can't ping the interface `192.168.1.1` from Linux machine.

Note: I could ping the interface `192.168.1.1` when I have one network card on linux machine:

```
[root@dd ~]# ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:48:23:C0  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe48:23c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:267464 (261.1 KiB)  TX bytes:41002 (40.0 KiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000
```

so what should I do to let eth0.1 to ping the interface, what I am missing?

Comment: Why did you make a sub-interface for vlan1 on the Linux box?  Is Vlan 1 tagged, or untagged on your switch?  Or in Cisco terms, what is the native VLAN for the port on the switch the Linux box connects to?

Comment: Also, how are you creating the vlan interfaces on your Linux box.  This isn't consistent between distros.  Plus with `ip link` you can basically name your interfaces whatever you want, and have them linked to a particular vlan.

Comment: Are you actually using VLAN tagging on the switch? Do you have the same VLAN ID on the switch and on your eth0.1 interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO NOT use vlan #1, it's reserved in most of the gear I've ever used and won't work properly if you're using vlan tagging.

Reconfigure all your switches and servers to use something else (ie: vlan 3), and that should get you working.